# Java socket server shows blank window

Tags: java, swing, sockets, event-dispatch-thread

I'm writing a program that communcaties two clients through server When I run it without the start method, it works fine and looks like this

[image]

but when I try to listen for connections I only get blank white window. The program stops at `conn = server.accept()` which is quite logical because i dont have a client yet, but why doesn't it how anything?

---

Also, can I get rid of that white border somehow?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Server extends JFrame {
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket conn;
private JTextArea TA;
private JPanel panel1;
private final int port = 1234;

public Server() {
    super("Server");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    TA = new JTextArea();
    TA.setEditable(true);
    TA.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    TA.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    c.add(new JScrollPane(TA));
    setVisible(true);
    TA.append("Server started.");
}

public void start() {
    try {
        TA.append("ServerSocket created. \n Listering for connections...");
        server = new ServerSocket(port, 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            conn = server.accept();
            TA.append("User " + i + " connected");
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
}
}

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
```

`

```
 public class ServerLauncher {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            Server s = new Server();
    //  s.start();
        }

    });

}

}
```

i was following a youtube guide to write this, and it gets the same bug but looks like it's discontinued after part 3 so I never found out how to fix it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqTB-S_5mss

Comment: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: @AndrewThompson ok, but where am I blocking the EDT and calling Thread.sleep ?

Comment: `conn = server.accept();` is blocking the EDT.

Comment: Note that first (two) comments are part of my 'copy/paste comments' that sometimes are slightly wrong for the exact situation.  Of course your code is not calling `Thread.sleep()`, but the call to accept a client socket potentially takes a long time (as long as it takes for two clients to connect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because scheduled in the AWT Event Dispatcher Thread and you're blocking it with the accept method, so nothing shows up.

Try this instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server s = new Server();
    s.start();
}


public Server() {
    super("Server");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    TA = new JTextArea();
    TA.setEditable(true);
    TA.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    TA.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    c.add(new JScrollPane(TA));
    setVisible(true);
    log(TA, "Server started.");
}

public void log(JTextArea txt, String message) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                txt.append(message);
            }});
}

public void start() {
    try {
        log(TA, "ServerSocket created. \n Listering for connections...");
        server = new ServerSocket(port, 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            conn = server.accept();
            log(TA, "User " + i + " connected");
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think i don't quie understand what `invokaLater` does. in try block, why is `log` called before server and executed after it, but not after let's say `conn`?

Comment: `invokeLater` simply queues up the `Runnable` so that it is executed by the AWT thread (the thread that manages UI updates) instead of the current thread (which is not the AWT thread). So if you have anything that takes a long time to execute, don't put it inside `invokeLater` otherwise you will get the AWT stuck and your UI will become unresponsive.

Answer (score 2):

- `invoking Server s = new Server();` from `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()`{ in `public class ServerLauncher {` is wrong idea, you wouldnt to start hard and long running code - `Workers Thread` from `invokeLater`(notifier for `Event Dispatch Thread`), more read in [Oracle tutorial Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) you would need to `start()` from `SwingWorker`, `Runnable#Thread`, `Thread`
- `TA.append("User " + i + " connected");` you have an issue with (again) with `Concurency in Swing`, all updates from `Worker Thread` must be done on EDT, wrapped into invokeLater()
- from `Runnable#Thread` to start `Server s = new Server();` then inside loop to `TA.append("User " + i + " connected");` wrapped into `invokeLater`